# How to calculate the inverse of the following matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to calculate the inverse of matrix $A=[a_{ij}]_{m.m}$, where
$a_{ii}=x_i+b$ and $a_{ij}=b~(i\neq j)$, for $1\leq i,j\leq m$.Can you help me?

Comment: Can you please show what you've done so far? So we can have a general direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to calculate the inverse of (here $m=3$)
$$M=\left[\begin{matrix}x_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & x_3\end{matrix}\right]+\left[\begin{matrix}b & b & b \\ b & b & b \\ b & b & b\end{matrix}\right]$$
Assuming the $x_i$ are nonzero, you can use the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula)
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}x_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & x_3\end{matrix}\right]\\
u=[b,b,b]^T\\
v=[1,1,1]^T\\
M=A+u v^T\\
M^{-1}=A^{-1}-\frac{A^{-1}u v^TA^{-1}}{1+v^TA^{-1} u}$$

If several $x_i$ are zero, your matrix is not invertible. If just one of them is zero, you can partition your matrix into blocks, with one block being the $1\times 1$ block where $x_i=0$, and another block being the $(m-1)\times(m-1)$ block in which the Sherman-Morrison formula works. Then use [block matrix inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion).

Comment: You might want to add some details about what to do if one of the $x_i$'s is zero. Also one of the vectors $u$ and $v$ needs to be multiplied by $b$.

Comment: Can you determine elements of $M^{-1}$?